# If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $1/f$ is bounded on $[a,b].$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

$f(x) > 0$ is given for all $x\in [a,b]$.
I only got to this:

Let $c$ belong to $[a,b]$. Then,
for all $ε>0$, there exists $δ>0$,
such that, $|x-c|<δ\implies|f(x)-f(c)|<ε$.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on Mathjax.

Comment: thanx man.. it is very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A continuous function on a closed interval attains its minimum. As $f$ is positive, this minimum must be (strictly) positive. Its reciprocal is a bound for $1/f$.

Answer (score 0):

*Sketch of proof:* By the Extreme Value Theorem (or compactness in fancier language), $f$ attains a maximum and minimum on a closed interval $[a,b]$. Both of those are positive, call them $M$ and $m$ respectively. Then $1/f$ also attains a max and min, which is $1/m$ and $1/M$, and hence $1/f$ is bounded by $1/m$.

Comment: then there is no need to prove it with the limit definition?